# Assumptions on the underlying function for a binary classification problem

Tags: machine-learning, classification, supervised-learning

Consider the binary classification problem, and let the feature space be denoted as $S$. What we are assuming is that there is an underlying function $F$, mapping from feature space S to the set containing two elements -1 and 1, that is $F:S\to\{-1,1\}$. Can we make only additional assumption that this underlying function $F$ is also a piece-wise constant function and no further assumptions.  That is the function $F$ maps feature space to the two element set containing 1 and -1, and additionally it is a  piece-wise constant function. How safe is this assumption? I hope to design a learning algorithm and lets say the algorithm learns a function $f_n$ for a certain data set of size $n$, then the learning algorithm is such that, as $n\to \infty$, $f_n \to F$ pointwise in all points of $S$ except at points of discontinuity of $F$.

With this assumption, the generalization ability of such an algorithm would be infinite?

Comment: @ArtemMavrin : For a counter example consider $S$ as $(0,1)$ and define $F$ as $F(x) = 1$ if $x$ is rational and $F(x) = -1$, if $x$ is irrational.

Comment: @ArtemMavrin : But then, my example was a pathological. So you mean to say albeit the only way, but its still a safe thing to proceed and design an algorithm like the one I mentioned? (converging pointwise as data size grows)

Comment: With this assumption, the generalization ability of such an algorithm would be infinite?

Comment: your question doesn't make much sense. generalization ability is not a number, and has nothing to do with asymptotic properties of the algorithm. there is plenty of algorithms that respect those properties, and they may have different generalization performance (you defined your model on deterministic terms, I assume that that is a p convergence).

Comment: @carlo : Thanks for the comment. I just wanted to keep things simple, t get to the main point I am asking (thats why deterministic). My main question is exactly that. Why do methods that pointwise converge to the underlying binary step functions are not the best classifiers. For example take spline interpolation or RBF, they fit any training data exactly (universal approximants) and as data points go to infinity, they converge pointwise to the underlying step function. What mre can be expected is my question? Why are they not the best candidates! Why should we go for SVM or anything?

Comment: spline interpolation is not generally an universal approximant, SVM with RBF kernel is. in some cases however, you may prefer a less powerful approximant which has useful inductive bias. this depends on your problem, but most famous case is CNNs, which are not universal approximants.

Comment: @corlo : When I am saying universal approximation, I mean can approximate (not all continuous functions as the case in neural nets), but can approximate all step functions. (sorry for using the wrong word). A Linear spline does that for step functions. SVM cant do that. When you cant separate using SVM, we need to change to a different kernel and try. But How can we say SVM is better generalization. All these questions I have is due to my lack of understanding of difference between generalization and pointwise convergence to underlying step function. Any good reference for this?

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is not enough to conclude infinite generalisability unless $S$ is finite.

In the case where $S$ is finite (and each element of $S$ has nonzero measure) then your argument works; with a large enough data set you expect more and more observations at each $x \in S$, and the chance of covering $S$ completely tends to 1.

In the case where $S$ isn't finite, the only way you can hope to generalise to $x \in S$ that you haven't "seen" yet is to make a continuity assumption on $F$. Obviously you can't assume $F$ is continuous because it can't take values between 0 and 1, but you can fix this by assuming that $F$ is the sign of an underlying continuous function $G$.

If you don't make such an assumption then you can never hope to generalise functions with dense discontinuities (such as your example of classifying rationals)